# How to insert a button using classname tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, gmail

i try to insert a button in gmail page.
it works fine using `getElementsbyTagName()` and `appendchild()`.

But i want to insert the button in a classname like

i am also tried `getElementsByClassName()`,`document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0]` and `querySelectorAll()`.

i have got a

```
mainDiv value from <div id=:ab>

var mainDiv=document.getElementById(':ab');
              var newDiv=document.createElement('div'); 
              newDiv.setAttribute('id','innerdiv11');
              var newButton=document.createElement('input');
              newButton.type='button'; 
              newButton.value='Encrypt';
              newButton.id='btn11';
              newDiv.appendChild(newButton);
              //mainDiv.insertBefore(newDiv, mainDiv.lastChild);
              mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Now i need to get `mainDiv value from <div class="abc">` value.

How can i achieve this?

i am using chrome browser.

Regards
Sanju

Answer (score 0):

When you do sth like
 var abc_array= document.getElementsByClassName("abc"); abc_array will have the array with the elements with "abc" class. You need to write a simple loop to find the value like...

```
 var class_string =[]; 
 for(var i=0;i<abc_array.length;i++){ 
     class_string=class_string.push(abc_array.innerHTML);
  }
//now you can return which class_string[0] or whatever you want.
```

Comment: @ Jack: abc_array length value is 0.